# Replace all references to variable in CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

I have a code-tree generated with CodeDOM that serializes to code similar to this:

```
MyClass 
{
    MyClass() 
    {
        this.thePropertyField = 1;
    }

    private int thePropertyField;
    int TheProperty 
    {
        get { return this.thePropertyField; }, 
        set { this.thePropertyField = value; }
    }
}
```

The class was built from an XSD.

Now I want to delete all the private backing-fields and invoke a method within the getters and setters. This works fine, however now - as the backing-fields are deleted - I have to replace all occurences of the private backingfield `thePropertyField` with the property `TheProperty`.

I thought about looping the statements within the constrcutor:

```
var ctor = type.Members.OfType<CodeConstructor>().FirstOrDefault();
if (ctor != null)
{
    var statements = ctor.Statements.Cast<CodeStatement>();
}
```

But know I don´t know further how to remove those statements that references a backing-field and add one that references the property instead.

Comment: The easiest probably would be to threat them as synonyms. Keep both, replace both. In your case `thePropertyField` should also become a property (`private` property) calling same methods as `TheProperty` does (btw, you miss `public`). This way you don't need to search for all references, only change definitions.

Comment: @Sinatr I know about missing `public`, just too lazy :). Anyway making the fields themeselfes properties implies that they come from the schema which they don´t, only the actual properties exist in my model. The fields however are just implementation-details that don´t exist in the model and should therefor also not go to the API.